# Haven´t found how to convert a num to a float

Tags: kotlin

i am trying to convert a num toFloat but i dont find anything useful at the moment,
Does anyone know how to do it?

I am using this to obtain the number in the string but i don´t find how to convert it to float
val str = "awdafafaf123asfasf"
val num = str.replace(Regex("[^0-9]"),"")
println(num)
}

Comment: "dont find anything useful". where have you looked? simply googling "convert to float kotlin" gives you the answer easily. Before asking something here it's expected that you did some effort to try find the answer yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.to*()` category of functions to convert a string to various other data types.
For example:

```kotlin
val str = "awdafafaf123asfasf" 
val num = str.replace(Regex("[^0-9]"),"")
val intValue: Int = num.toInt()
val doubleValue: Double = num.toDouble()
val floatValue: Float = num.toFloat()
println(num)
```

Kotlin standard library also provides `String.to*OrNull()` versions of these functions which return `null` if conversion is not possible.

Comment: thanks, this helps me